# Does it make sens to use fluentd for IOT devices data collection

Tags: iot, fluentd, data-collection

I am building a system that collects different IOT devices data. Data can come from different sources or providers like http, CSV or TCP. After few research I came across fleuntd. This seems to be what I need but I noticed it is mostly used for "log collection in Kubernetes clusters".

Does it make sens to use it for IOT data collection? Is there any limitation or problem that I could come across if I decide to go with it?

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO. However, you might want to look at https://fluentbit.io/ and compare it with `fluentd`. Depending on your resource constraints, you need to choose accordingly.